# How do I convert a classic ActorContext to a typed one

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor, akka-typed

Say I define some messages:

```
sealed trait Command
case class A(i: Int) extends Command
case class B(str: String) extends Command
```

And then a classic actor as below to handle these messages. On creation I need access to the ActorContext but as a typed context not a classic

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  val typedContext: ActorContext[Command] = ???

  def receive = {
    case A(i) =>
      // Do something with i
    case B(str)
     // Do something with str

  }
}
```

I know I can do self.toTyped[Command] to get the typed self reference. But I cannot find anything similar for the ActorContext. How would I go about converting?

Comment: What do you want to do with this `typedContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conversion from a classic `ActorContext` to a typed `ActorContext`.  About the only things a typed `ActorContext` can do that a classic `ActorContext` can't are:

- ask another actor and adapt the result (to do that in classic, you use the classic ask pattern: `import akka.pattern.ask`)
- pipe a future to the actor (for that `import akka.pattern.pipe`)
- take advantage of a typed actor's lifecycle (spawn, watch, unwatch, stop)

For the last one, you can

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter.ClassicActorContextOps
```

which will add

- `spawn`/`spawnAnonymous`
- `watch`
- `unwatch`
- `stop`

methods which handle typed.